# How to add another row to my Database through SQLite add-on for Firefox?

Tags: objective-c, ipad, sqlite

I am just starting with SQLite in my Iphone Apps, I created the database with SQLite add-on for Firefox and ran the app it was good. But now i am trying to add another row to it and see its working but for some reason i am able to add another row but couldn't see it in my app.
Here's the code i am using to loop through rows.

```
-(void) readAnimalsFromDatabase {
    // Setup the database object
    sqlite3 *database;

    // Init the animals Array
    animals = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    // Open the database from the users filessytem
    if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
        // Setup the SQL Statement and compile it for faster access
        const char *sqlStatement = "select * from animals";
        sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
            // Loop through the results and add them to the feeds array
            while(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
                // Read the data from the result row
                NSString *aName = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 1)];
                NSString *aDescription = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 2)];
                NSString *aImageUrl = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 3)];

                // Create a new animal object with the data from the database
                Animal *animal = [[Animal alloc] initWithName:aName description:aDescription url:aImageUrl];

                // Add the animal object to the animals Array
                [animals addObject:animal];

                [animal release];
            }
        }
        // Release the compiled statement from memory
        sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);

    }
    sqlite3_close(database);

}

-(void) checkAndCreateDatabase{
    // Check if the SQL database has already been saved to the users phone, if not then copy it over
    BOOL success;

    // Create a FileManager object, we will use this to check the status
    // of the database and to copy it over if required
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    // Check if the database has already been created in the users filesystem
    success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:databasePath];

    // If the database already exists then return without doing anything
    if(success) return;

    // If not then proceed to copy the database from the application to the users filesystem

    // Get the path to the database in the application package
    NSString *databasePathFromApp = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];

    // Copy the database from the package to the users filesystem
    [fileManager copyItemAtPath:databasePathFromApp toPath:databasePath error:nil];

    [fileManager release];
}
```

Please help me with this.
Thanks,

Comment: Actually whenever your are working with sqlite the database gets saved in the folder user/library/application support/iphone simulator/app folder. You need to go there and delete the database and then run the app again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually whenever your are working with sqlite the database gets saved in the folder user/library/application support/iphone simulator/app folder. You need to go there and delete the database and then run the app again.